# Sort QList items based on dependencies using std::sort

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have `QString`s of item names such as "Put coffee", "Start coffee machine" or "Pour milk into coffee". I have such class to describe dependency (stripped of irrelevant stuff):

```
class ImportWithDependency {
public:
    // varargs je pro lenochy
    ImportWithDependency(const QString& itemName, const QString& dependsOn = "", const QString& dependsOn2="", const QString& dependsOn3 = "")
        : NAME(itemName)
        , LOCALISED_NAME(getViewLocalisedName(viewName))
    {
        if (!dependsOn.isEmpty())
            dependencies << dependsOn;
        if (!dependsOn2.isEmpty())
            dependencies << dependsOn2;
        if (!dependsOn3.isEmpty())
            dependencies << dependsOn3;
    }
    // cannot be const for sorting
    QString NAME;
    QStringList dependencies;
};
```

I want to sort items of `QList<MyDependencyInfo>` so that no item is preceded by item which depends on it.

I created the following comparator:

```
class ImportDependencyComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(const ImportWithDependency& a, const ImportWithDependency& b) const
    {
        // check if a depends on b
        if (a.dependencies.contains(b.NAME))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

I init the list like this:

```
    QList<ImportWithDependency> views;
    views << ImportWithDependency("A");
    // B depends on A
    views << ImportWithDependency("B", "A");
    // C depends on A
    views << ImportWithDependency("C", "A");
    // D depends on B
    views << ImportWithDependency("D", "B");
```

And I sort like this:

```
std::sort(views.begin(), views.end(), ImportDependencyComparator());
```

And the result is:

D B C A

Instead of:

A B C D

The order I'm getting seems to be random, though same every time. What's wrong? Can this even be used for sorting?

Comment: Look at [Topological_sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Comment: Your comparator is broken for `std::sort` as `D` doesn't depend of `A` (through `B`).

Comment: BTW, you reverse the logic, if dependencies were complete, it would be `return !a.dependencies.contains(b.NAME);`

Comment: [OT]: passing directly `QStringList` instead of 3 `QString` seems more logical (even if call sites become `ImportWithDependency("B", {"A"})`).